# Add notes in the equation under brace

Tags: equations, tex-core, empheq

How to write the equation shown in the image[image: adding notes under the term in a mathematical equation]

Answer (score 5):

You could use `\overbrace` and `\underbrace`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
    \overbrace{a}^{\text{output}} = \underbrace{b}_{\text{significant}} + \underbrace{c + d}_{\text{non significant}}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```